# How to click on drop-down list by selenium package in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, web-scraping

I want to click on drop-down list. I have a drop-down list by this x-path:

```
//*[@id="resultsPerPage-button"]/span[1]
```

This drop-down list have four buttons namely 20,50,100,200. I want to click on "200". X-path of "200" is:

```
//*[@id="ui-id-4"]
```

I I used this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
number=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="resultsPerPage-button"]/span[2]""")
number.click()
number.send_keys()
var200=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ui-id-4"]""")
var200.click()
time.sleep(5)
var200.send_keys("200")
```

But it takes an error like this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <span class="ui-selectmenu-text"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

What should I do?
In fact "200" button is not recognized as a button.

Comment: Share HTML code for the same

Comment: <span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon btn-primary btn-icon ico-navigate-down flexDisplay flexAlignCenter flexJustifyCenter"></span>

Comment: I mean for the whole drop-down

Comment: <ul aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="resultsPerPage-button" id="resultsPerPage-menu" role="listbox" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-corner-bottom ui-widget ui-widget-content" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-4" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 71px;"><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-1" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">20</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">50</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">

Comment: 100</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper ui-state-active">200</div></li></ul>

Comment: Because of limitation of characters, I send the html code in two sections.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. But, I can solve it. The answer will be proposed.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve my problem by some changes:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    import time
    number=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="resultsPerPage-button"]/span[2]""")
    number.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    #number.send_keys()
    time.sleep(10)
    # find the "200" key and send key on it
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ui-id-4"]""").send_keys("200")
    #find the "200" key and click on it
    d=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ui-id-4"]""").click()
    time.sleep(5)
```